# Pandas new column based in sum a column from another pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, being the first one:

```
   unit    year
0     1    2020
1     2    2021
2     3    2022
```

and the second:

```
   unit    observations
0     1               0
1     2               1
2     2               2
3     2               3
4     2               4
5     3               5
```

I need to add a column at the first dataframe as a sum of observations for the unit at the second dataframe, I have something like this at the end

```
   unit    year   observations
0     1    2020              0
1     2    2021             10
2     3    2022              5
```

I tried to df_1.iterrows and using a query based in the unit from the first df to sum, and it worked, but I'm talking about a df with about to 4 million rows, this solution will take days. Someone have a quicker solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with aggregate `sum` in second DataFrame:

```
df1['observations'] = df1['unit'].map(df2.groupby('unit')['observations'].sum())
print (df1)
   unit  year  observations
0     1  2020             0
1     2  2021            10
2     3  2022             5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was exactly what I needed.
If I was to count how many rows that i have for this unit instead of sum, how it can be done?

Comment: @CarlosEduardoBarros - then use `df1['no_observations'] = df1['unit'].map(df2['unit'].value_counts())`